# Access 2019 SQL query with aliases, Joins, and Aggregation Error Message

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am well-versed in T-SQL, but new to SQL in Microsoft Access 2019.  I am getting an error message of

> Your query does not Include the specified expression "Hospital" as part of an aggregate function.

Hospital is an alias for ResellerName in the DimReseller Table in AdventoreWorks.  My Code is below:

```
SELECT USRegion, ZipCode, State, StateCD, City
,ResellerName AS Hospital
,LastName+', '+FirstName AS Doctor
, IllnessName
, DimProduct.ProductKey AS IllnessCode
, OrderDate as VisitDate
, sum(OrderQuantity) as Prescriptions
, Count(SalesOrderNumber) as Visits 
, sum(Population) as USPopulation

FROM ((((DIMSalesTerritory INNER JOIN DIMGeoUSwithPopulation

 ON DimSalesTerritory.SalesTerritoryKey = DimGeoUSwithPopulation.SalesTerritoryKey) 

INNER JOIN DIMReseller ON DimGeoUSwithPopulation.GeographyKey = DIMReseller.GeographyKey)

INNER JOIN FACTResellerSales ON DimReseller.ResellerKey = FactResellerSales.ResellerKey) 

INNER JOIN DIMProduct ON FACTResellerSales.ProductKey = DIMProduct.ProductKey) 

INNER JOIN Employee ON FactResellerSales.EmployeeKey = Employee.EmployeeKey

Group by USRegion, ZipCode, State, StateCd, City, Hospital, Doctor, IllnessName, IllnessCode, VisitDate 
;
```

I have tried inner, outer, and right joins & mixing different types of joins.  I do not appear to have problems with other aliases such as Doctor or IllnessCode.  I have tried rearranging the order of the joins a few times.  I have moved Hospital to different spots in the group by list.  I have done data checks on the DimReseller table joined to FactResellerSales alone & found data.  Joins are different in Access SQL vs T-SQL and I have possibly made an error there.  I am attempting to create a work sample for a prospective employer & would appreciate any help!

thanks,
Ginger

Answer (score 1):

In the GROUP BY clause you must use the original column names / computations, not the aliases.

So you need:

```
GROUP BY USRegion, ZipCode, State, StateCd, City
, ResellerName
, LastName+', '+FirstName
, IllnessName
, DimProduct.ProductKey 
, OrderDate
```

Comment: Thanks Andre! I appreciate your help.